# strange output for swap

Tags: partitioning, swap

I have to make a fullbackup of my ubuntu bionic.  I run

```
sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdc
NAME   FSTYPE    LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdc                                                         
├─sdc1 ext4            8cc02316-1cd7-4f54-bd1a-c3f174e55251 /media/alex/8cc02316-1cd7-4f54-bd1a-c3f174e55251
├─sdc2 swsuspend       f923fdf9-3416-420d-898c-e481c82a757b 
├─sdc3                                                      
└─sdc5 ext4            f7217969-9cde-4eff-940b-761ebb06189b /media/alex/f7217969-9cde-4eff-940b-761ebb06189b
```

If I understood right, it has something to do with suspend to disk. Can I remove this mark `swsuspend` without formating swap? I will avoid to change The UUID in /etc/fstab a.s.o.

Comment: ...remove it why? If this is a swap partition, there is no need to back it up. Also, it is a filesystem type, so I don't see how you can remove it without altering the filesystem.

Comment: I made the backup the way I can plugin this drive in worst case my ubuntu bionic is brocken so I can interchange  it and work with the backupharddrive. I'm afraid it wont boot because of the swap. But if no other way I format it and change the UUID in the relevant files. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix it without reformating. Tried different bootoptions, could login. Now filesystem is shown as swap.